# Labelling point elevations of raster (DEM) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, dem, buffer, query

I'm trying to create a map with spot levels using an underlying 1m resolution DEM TIFF file. My thought process so far is to create a grid of points with a height value field over the area of interest (say 6m x 6m) and then select the highest in each cell. Then draw a 5 buffer around all these points. If any of these buffers contain more than 1 point keep the highest value and delete the rest. This should result in nicely spaced point that I can label neatly without overlaps or the chance of the label not being the highest.

I've tried making a template for this using the Graphical Modeller, but I'm not great with expressions (I have more of a survey/cartography background and its been a while since I did this at school!)

What is the best way to go about achieving this?

Images attached showing graphically what I'm trying to achieve.

Alternatively is there a way to use labels to give greater weight to points with a higher elevation field so that they are displayed instead of the lower values?

[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/zd67utxlssu51.jpg?width=1392&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=abafc89bb2d64a118b1e8f0d2c1abe6784a14d46))</sub>

6x6m grid cells

[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/sm7v7hrnssu51.jpg?width=1392&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=ce5e473611d708ec7f5bfbd8f30d0c0a3df9bf20))</sub>

Highest value in each cell

[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/8uwflz9qssu51.jpg?width=1351&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=26a5c61ead1c889122044f4c8900ff0af16da7cc))</sub>

5m radius from high point in each cell. Keep highest point in each circle buffer that contains >1 points

[image: Text]
<sub>(source: [redd.it](https://preview.redd.it/x86g5r9tssu51.jpg?width=1341&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=ee3556085e692e9c8b97e034e72b165052da599a))</sub>

remaining points for DEM elevation labelling

[image]
example of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Couldn't you resample the DEM to your desired size (say 6x6m) and only then convert to points to display the values?

Comment: I should have clarified that the position of the highest point is critical for the plan (shows minimum clearance to under water obstructions on nautical navigation plans). See example image here
[Example plan clip](https://i.imgur.com/22NO36h.jpg)

Comment: You can use gdalwarp with the resampling method set to max

Comment: I spent some time in the modeler and have something that works but the problem is that it's not practical until there is a way to append algorithm output to an existing layer (from what I understand it is an unsolved bug).